# Make Jenkins start a Batch without running forever?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

How would I go about making a Jenkins server start a .bat file, that runs forever as it starts a server program, without having Jenkins run forever until the bat file is ended manually or by error?

Could this be solved by making Jenkins call a bat file which calls the server bat file thar runs forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detach execution from the main process, similar to the `&` operator in Linux.

If you bath file is named `run-forever.bat`, then create another batch file named `forever-starter.bat` that does this :

```
@start "" cmd /c run-forever.bat
```